# Doesn't "scrollwheelup/down" mapping work in gvim on windows OS?

Tags: vim, mouse, scrolling, keymap, scroll-wheel

I tried it all ways to make the mouse buttons ScollWheelUp/Down work in my vim.

Checked in all other plugins if there is a conflicting map, no conflicting map.
Tried this:

```
:verbose map <ScrollWheelUp> --> No mapping found
:verbose map <ScrollWheelDown> --> No mapping found
```

But then I tried this nothing happens:

```
noremap <ScrollWheelUp>   :echo "scrollup"<CR>
noremap <ScrollWheelDown> :echo "scrolldown"<CR>
```

Same with maps like these

Can it be a windows problem?
When I scroll my mouse in vim the page scrolls 3 lines as in every other application on my OS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately no, they don't work in Windows. `:help scroll-mouse-wheel` specifically mentions that they are for the X11 GUIs:

```
For the X11 GUIs (Motif, Athena and GTK) scrolling the wheel generates key
presses <ScrollWheelUp>, <ScrollWheelDown>, <ScrollWheelLeft> and
<ScrollWheelRight>.
```